# HTML Input - Remove leading Character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have an HTML form showing a table where the user can scan a product barcode to enter the serial number into a text input field like this:

```
<td id="9856623"><input type="text" class="form-control serialNumber" placeholder="Serial #" name="serialNumber" autocomplete="off" value=""></td>
```

When the cursor is in the input field the user scans a barcode to insert the barcode value into this input field, which then triggers a script that runs in the background to do a database update via PHP. We need to check if the first characters in the serial number that is scanned is an 'S' and if so then remove this. We handle this in PHP like this:

```
$serialNumber = 'STRQWEF412421';

$serialFirstChar = substr( $serialNumber , 0, 1);

if ($serialFirstChar == 'S') {
    $serialNumber = substr($serialNumber, 1);
}
```

but I now need to do the same in Javascript to update the entered serial number in the text input field so also remove the leading 'S' character if present. Here's the current script that runs when the Serial Number is entered:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-control.serialNumber").change(function() {
    //$("input[type='text']").change(function(){
    //alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
    var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var recid = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
    var serialNumber = $(this).val();
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('updateAsset.php', {
      type: 'updateDatabase',
      recid: recid,
      serialNumber: serialNumber
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        var ajaxError = (data.text);
        var errorAlert = 'There was an error updating the Serial Number - ' + ajaxError + '. Please contact the Helpdesk';
        $this.closest('td').addClass("has-error");
        //display AJAX error details
        $("#serialNumberErrorMessage").html(errorAlert);
        $("#serialNumberError").show();
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        var dateReceived = (data.dateReceived);
        $this.closest('td').addClass("has-success")
        $this.closest('td').removeClass("has-error");
        $this.closest('tr').children('.DateReceived').html(dateReceived);
        // if you want to show a success alert enable the following
        // $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-success").html(data.text);
      }

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an error updating the Serial Number - AJAX request error. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + '. Please contact the Helpdesk';
      $this.closest('td').addClass("has-error");
      //display AJAX error details
      $("#serialNumberErrorMessage").html(ajaxError);
      $("#serialNumberError").show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have no idea how to go about this at this point, and whether I can update my existing script to also update the entered serial number and remove any leading 'S' character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`string#charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)** and **[`string#substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/substring)**, like this:

```js
var serialNumber = 'STRQWEF412421';
if (serialNumber.charAt(0) === 'S') {
    serialNumber = serialNumber.substr(1);
}
console.log(serialNumber);
```

**Edit:**

So to apply this code for your `input` you need to add it in the `change` event handler like this:

```
$(".form-control.serialNumber").change(function() {

  var serialNumber = $(this).val();
  if (serialNumber.charAt(0) === 'S') {
    $(this).val(serialNumber.substr(1));
  }
  //Rest of the code
});
```

Comment: Thanks @chsdk - that works well. I'm now stumped about how to update the input field with the new updated serialNumber value. Any ideas?

Comment: @user982124 Yes you need to use the `.value` property of the input, in the `change` event. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Javascript's [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith). If the first charactes is `S`, remove it from the string:

```js
// for debugging
serialNumber = 'STRQWEF412421';

if (serialNumber.startsWith('S'))
    serialNumber = serialNumber.substring(1);
        
console.log(serialNumber);
```

Comment: We need just to mention that [`startsWith` isn't fully covered by all browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-String.prototype.startsWith).

Answer (score 0):

if cropping first letter is what u want then this can help;

```
let stringFromScanner = "ScannedString";
if(stringFromScanner.substr(0,1) == "S" || stringFromScanner.substr(0,1) == "s") {
   stringFromScanner.slice(1,stringFromScanner.length);
}
```